# Computing the minimal flexible distance of two vectors using dynamic programming

Tags: recurrence-relation, dynamic-programming, recursion

I can't figure out a recurrence equation for a dynamic programming assignment. Formally, we aim
to minimize the total sum of distances between matched points with the following constraints:

- Every point from both vectors has to be matched at least once, but can be matched multiple
  times.
- A point `i` can only be matched with a point `j` if no point `o` is matched with a point `u` such that `i < o` and `j > u` or `i > o` and
  `j < u`, i.e., the ‘lines’ of the matches are not allowed to cross.

In order to compute the distance between two matched points, we use the absolute difference.

(Easy) Example input:

```
1.0 2.0 2.4 3.5
2.0 2.1 2.0 3.2
```

Should output:

```
1.8
```

Because in this example `|1.0 - 2.0| + |2.0 - 2.1| + |2.4 - 2.0| + |3.5 - 3.2|` is optimal

The assignment hints to sequence alignment which I thoroughly studied and came across the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm. However, I can't figure out how to adapt it to this problem.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: It looks like you might have accidentally created two accounts.  I encourage you to merge them: http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.  This will ensure you retain access to your question and are able to edit it and post comments on this page.

Comment: You may find [Levenshtein's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) very useful in order to understand this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a programming assignment, I only show some hints.

Consider two vectors $\vec{a} = a_1 \cdots a_i \cdots a_m$ and $\vec{b} = b_1 \cdots b_j \cdots b_n$.

First, please prove the following

> *Observation:* $a_m$ must be matched with $b_n$.

Second, consider the following subproblems,

$$D(i,j) \triangleq \text{the optimal (matching) distance between } a_1 \cdots a_i \text{ and } b_1 \cdots b_j.$$

and answer the following question

> Given the observation above, what is the relationship between $D_{i,j}$ and $D(i-1, j)$, $D(i, j-1)$, or maybe $D(i-1, j-1)$?